# Shell script to search for a word in a while block of the C program

Tags: shell, awk, sed, scripting

I want to search for a word "while" in a file and if the file contains the word then in the given block of while i need to search for another word "Hello" if hello is present then its line no should be printed.

Please help in this regard 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: `code` 
while (condition)
{
How old are you
HelloHoware you
}

Hello 
`code`

Now in this scenario only line number 4 should be printed since it contains Hello in while block.

Comment: i had seen multi-line while function.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the example - it's not readable or useful as a comment.

Comment: Your question is _difficult_ in the sense that if I want to find the string `"hello"` in a `while` block, I'd have to write a parser for `C`, sort of...  If you could narrow your problem, posing some further constraint, it could become more manageable in the space of a short response.

Comment: `code` <br/>
while (condition) <br/>
{<br/>
How old are you<br/>
HelloHoware you<br/>
}<br/>
<br/>
Hello<br/> 
`code`<br/>
<br/>
Now in this scenario only line number 4 should be printed since it contains Hello in while block.<br/>

Comment: no thats what the issue is that i need to do the same using Shell scripting if possible

Comment: Stop trying to put formatted text in comments as you simply cannot. You need to edit your question to add whatever formatted text youre trying to show us.

Comment: You cannot do this job without writing a C parser. For example if you have `char *a="while(1) { say hello }"` that is not a while loop its a text string but how would you write a shell script to understand the difference without understanding the syntax and semantics of C? Its even worse than that because symbols have different meanings in different C standards (e.g. `//` in C99 can be the start of a comment but not so in ANSI-C).

Comment: A full unconditional search will need a C Parser.  Simply counting of the opening bracelet '{' and closing bracelet '}' won't work fine, since the input may have `#if 0  ... #endif` or comment lines with imbalanced bracelets. It is very difficult, unless with some constraints for easier parsing.

Comment: It can be done if balanced bracelet pairs are assumed.  Yet still a difficult job.  The question is still not clear: Do we need to seek for while blocks in comment lines?  "Hello" in comment lines, etc...

Comment: thanks for the reasonings given a basic code to know that if the word exists in a given block or any answer near to it will surely help me.
Its not a project just needed by me to debug a code having 55000 lines so reducing the search space will surely help

Comment: I'd start by counting how many "hello"s you have in your 55 KLOC, "grep hello *.c | wc -l" and, if they're not that many, I'll use `emacs` or a similar text editor to inspect all the "hello"s.

Comment: I was doing the same and hence needed the solution to not to do it manually.
It was 500 places

Answer (score -2):

Some like this?

```
cat file
Hi

This is a bloc
It may have while word
Here is Hello too

In this block
we have while
but not the other word
```

```
awk -v RS="" '/while/ && /Hello/' file
This is a bloc
It may have while word
Here is Hello too
```

Here each block is separated by an empty line.
To make `awk` work in block modus, set `RS` to nothing.
Then search for all line with both `while` and `Hello`

---

If you like to search for `while` in the whole file, and then if its found, print block with `Hello`, do:

```
awk -v RS="" 'FNR==NR && /while/ {f=1;next} f && /Hello/'  file file
```

This reads `file` two times.  First time search for `while` and if found set  `f`
Second time, if `f` is true, and `Hello` is found, print block.

Comment: I think you've missed the point of the question - he's looking for words within a `while (condition) { body }` block in a C program.